Closed form expression for sum of floor of square roots
To find the sum of $\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor$ from k=0 to k=m, I first realized that the floor of the square root gives $n$ for the interval $[n^2, (n+1)^2)$. Within that interval, I found that the number of integers is given by:
$$(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$$
Thus, in this interval, the contribution to the sum can be expressed as $n(2n+1)$. Now, to sum them up, I used:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor}n(2n+1)$$
However, the challenge arises in determining how many intervals we need to sum over. Specifically, it can be difficult to decide whether to include the entire interval or only a few terms from it. For example, if I want to compute the sum up to $5$, I would need to include the interval corresponding to $2$, but I only need $2$ terms (i.e., $2$ values of $\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor$) from that interval, not the entire interval.
I found a previous answer stating that we need to sum from $0$ to $\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1$, but that is unclear to me.

"the sum of $\lfloor\sqrt k\rfloor$" has a value only when you say what are the values of $k$ that the sum ranges over. Presumably you're looking at consecutive integer values of $k$; do they start at $k=1$ and end at $k=m$, or something else? The question would be improved if you stated the original sum that you're trying to find and if you used the same precise summation notation in that problem statement as you do in the attempted answer.

Sorry for the confusion, I have edited it. Original sum was from k = 0 to k =m. After I did the "n" thing, the sum became from n=0 to n=floor[sqrt(m)] (which I don't think is correct)

I guess the previous answer you refer to is the accepted answer of this question. The business about summing to $\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1$ instead of $\sqrt m$ has to do with the way that answer groups the repeated terms in the original sum, and also has a lot to do with the fact that that answer is correct only when $m+1$ is a perfect square. In every other case the main equation of the answer is wrong, precisely because it doesn't sum the last few terms. I suggest you look at literally any other answer to that question.

I guess the previous answer you refer to is the accepted answer of this question.
In that answer, as in your attempt, they first attempt to collect the equal terms of the sum together as an inner sum.
Rewritten to suit your problem statement and notation
(summing the original sum from $0$ to $m$ rather than $1$ to $n$
and using $n$ rather than $p$ in the inner sum), their attempt says that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor
\stackrel?=
\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1} \,
\sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor.  \tag1
$$
So the inner sum is the sum of $2n+1$ copies of the term
$\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor = n$ occurring $2n+1$ times,
which, as you correctly deduced, is the correct way to add up all the "entire" intervals of identical terms that occur in the original sum,
where an "entire" interval is the subsequence of identical terms that occur from a term $\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$ where $k$ is a perfect square, that is, from $k=n^2$, to the term $\lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor$ where $k$ is the integer just before the next perfect square, that is, to $k = (n+1)^2-1$.
But Equation $(1)$ is correct only in the case where $m+1$ is a perfect square, because that's when $\sqrt m$ is the last integer whose square root has integer part
$\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor$. (That's why I wrote $\stackrel?=$ instead of $=$.)
Because the inner sum runs from $k=n^2$ to $k=(n+1)^2-1$,
we need to have $m=(n+1)^2-1$.
Solving for $m$, we get $\sqrt{m+1}-1$.
Then when $n = \sqrt{m+1}-1$ we find $2n+1$ terms in the inner sum, all equal to
$\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor$.
When $m+1$ is not a perfect square, $\sqrt{m+1}-1$ is not an integer and we don't have an "entire" interval of copies of $\lfloor\sqrt{m}\rfloor$ at the end of the sum.
The "not an integer" part is solved by the greatest integer function:
the last value of the index $n$ is
$$n = \lfloor\sqrt{m+1}-1\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{m+1}\rfloor - 1.$$
But the maximum value of $k$ in the double sum is $k = (n+1)^2-1$ where
$n = \lfloor\sqrt{m+1}\rfloor - 1$, that is,
$k = \lfloor\sqrt{m+1}\rfloor^2 - 1$.
We also need to add terms where
$\lfloor\sqrt{m+1}\rfloor^2 \leq k \leq m$.
So to correct the equation so it works for all positive $m$, we can write
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^m \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1} \,
   \sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor\right)
 + \sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor^2}^{m} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor \\
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1} n(2n + 1)\right)
  + (m - \lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor^2 + 1) \lfloor \sqrt{m} \rfloor.
\end{align}
That is, we split the original sum into a double sum that adds up all the "entire" intervals and a "tail" sum that adds up any terms after the last "entire" interval.
Note that the formula $\lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor-1$ appears in the sum because of the desire to include as many "entire" intervals of equal terms in the main part of the sum as possible. In the case where $m+1$ is a perfect square, the last sum runs from $m+1$ to $m$, that is, it has no terms at all, and $m - \lfloor \sqrt{m+1}\rfloor^2 + 1$ also is zero.

The disadvantage of this approach is you end up with both $\sqrt{m+1}$ and $\sqrt{m}$ in your formulas and it's not immediately clear to me how to reduce this to just one kind of square root other than by going back to the beginning and starting over.
I can see two ways to construct the sum so that it involves $\sqrt{m}$ but not
$\sqrt{m+1}$.
One way is to let $n$ run from $0$ to $\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor-1$. This says that we never use the double sum to add up the terms equal to $\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor$ even if there happens to be an "entire" interval of those terms at the end of the sum.
Instead, we include those terms in the "tail" sum. Then the "tail" sum is never zero, but it sometimes adds up an "entire" interval. We can write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor
= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor-1} \,
   \sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor\right)
 + \sum_{k=\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor^2}^{m} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor \\
$$
and proceed from there.
Another way to avoid writing $\sqrt{m+1}$ is to let the double sum add up the "entire" interval that includes $\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor$. This will add up too many terms when
$m+1$ is not a perfect square, so we have to subtract those terms from the double sum in order to get the correct result.
The highest value of $n$ in the outer sum will be $\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor$ and for this $n$ the highest value of $k$ in the inner sum will be
$(\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor + 1)^2-1$. 
We can write
$$
\sum_{k=0}^m \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor
= \left(\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor} \,
   \sum_{k=n^2}^{(n+1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor\right)
 - \sum_{k=m+1}^{(\lfloor \sqrt{m}\rfloor + 1)^2-1} \lfloor \sqrt{k} \rfloor.
$$
This will lead to something like your formula,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt m\rfloor}n(2n+1),
$$
except that it will subtract away any terms that this formula adds up that are not in the original sum from $0$ to $m$.

Makes sense, thank you!! I never thought of splitting the sum and adding a "tail" part (I was too obsessed with making only one sum) but I guess this is the only way. :)

In the formula where we add the tail terms, how will we convert that tail sum into a closed form expression?

There are techniques with Iverson brackets that could fit this all in one sum, but due to your observation about how different the last subsequence of terms is, I just find it natural to think of it as an “extra” sum. I actually did evaluate the “tail” sum in the first example; all the terms are equal so you just need to count the terms in the sum (looking at the range of indexes) and multiply that by the value of the last term.
